# getting error @react-native-community_art:generateReleaseRFile when get android release with CI/CD tools (bamboo)

Tags: android, react-native, cicd, bamboo

our app produced for several companies so use react-native-config for creating profiles and use them in CI/CD (bamboo) when we run bamboo to make releases (android/iOS) for each profile at least for 3-4 profiles get error @react-native-community_art:generateReleaseRFile one solution is run "gradlew clean" but I cant always run it i want to solve it or make it automatic.

this error usually show by "react-native-community_art" but sometimes change to other libraries

the completed error is

> Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_art:generateReleaseRFile'
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask$GenerateLibRFileRunnable pathToDirectory/node_modules/@react-native-community/art/android/build/intermediates/local_only_symbol_list/release/R-def.txt

or

> Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_art:generateReleaseRFile'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask$GenerateLibRFileRunnable /pathTodProjectDirectory/node_modules/@react-native-community/art/android/build/intermediates/merged_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml

sometimes it gets in debug mood

how can i fix that please help me

react-native : 0.71.11/ 0.69.3

- remove all jCenter() from android gradle (installed dependencies)
- sync compilegradleVersion (installed dependencies and root project)
- rerun bamboo for fixe and continue to execute releasing app